# Unable to link Google Play Developer Account to Google Checkout

Tags: google-play, google-checkout

I am a Singapore based developer and my company (Singapore Company) has registered as a Google Play Developer.

According to Google (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324&topic=15867&ctx=topic and http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468) I am entitled to sell paid applications on Google Play, because my country, Singapore, is listed there.

The instructions clearly state that:

1) The Google Checkout account which I need to link to your Google Play developer account can only be linked once from within the developer account interface.

2) If you're interested in selling priced applications, you'll need to be registered as a Google Checkout Merchant as well. To do this from Google Play publisher site, I need to Log into my  Google Play Android Developer Console at https://play.google.com/apps/publish/, Click on the "Edit profile" link, and Select "Setup a Merchant Account at Google Checkout.

**However, when I log into my Google Play Developer console and click "edit profile" I don't see any link to allow me to link my Google Play developer account to Google Checkout. Nor do I see an option to create a new checkout account and then link it**. If I try to set up a Google checkout account independently, i.e. a "classic" checkout account, it only gives me 2 countries as an option - UK & USA (neither of which is where my company is located).

Any ideas on how I can get around this? I emailed Google Play support, but surprise surprise they haven't been able to solve this for me.

I am physically NOT located in Singapore at the moment - and I've tried logging in from a  US IP as well as from a non-US (but also non-Singapore) IP and neither of those did the trick.

I am DESPERATE - I have two apps ready to upload but have been unable to publish them because they are not meant to be free. I have tried everything I can think of to link my Google Play developer account with a new Google Checkout account but have been unable to do so.

Comment: have you tried upload the application and change the price?